# different declarations of array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Suppose that I have an array of pointers:

```
char *names[] = { "Za" , "John"};
```

Can I declare it like this:(?)

```
char **names = { "Za" , "John" }
```

The reason I am trying to do this is that I am trying to increment the array to print its contents such that I can do:

```
printf("%s \n" , *(++names))
```

So I can get printf to print "John".

I tried the declaration char **names and I got the following warning upon compilation:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:6:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  char **names = { "Za" , "John"};
  ^
test.c:6:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘names’) [enabled by default]
test.c:6:2: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
test.c:6:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘names’) [enabled by default]
```

P.S my C file name is test.c

Thanks.

Comment: You *do* know that a pointer to a pointer to `char` ***is*** not and can ***never*** be the same as an array of pointers to `char`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks for the insight, from what I said what would tell you that I don't? I am really trying to figure this out... A pointer to a pointer to char , is an address of another address of a character, while an array of pointers to char is an array of addresses of characters. Do I make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Just do `char **pCurrentName = names;`, then you'll be able to do `printf("%s \n" , *(++pCurrentName))`.

Comment: Thanks it works but I am really interested in the reasoning of why this works, and why what I did doesn't work.

Comment: @kolonel You should see a pointer variable as what it is, but an array used in pointer context rather as a value of an appropriate pointer. So you can use it for assignments, but you cannot assign it anything.

Comment: @glglgl thanks for commenting, but could you provide more details of what you think is wrong with my logic?

Comment: You're mixed up on the difference between an array and a pointer.  An array is a series of objects stored in contiguous memory locations. A pointer tells you where to find an object.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I don't think this is the problem. I just want to know if I have char **names , why I can't increment names++ the same way I increment temp++ if I had an array of the form char *temp ?

Comment: `char *temp;` isn't an array, it is a pointer. You can increment both `names` and `temp`. If those are pointers to an element of an array, then incrementing them will point to the next element in the same array. However, you cannot increment an array.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thanks but from the example in the question above  **names = { "Za" , "John" } , names cannot be incremented so I don't know what you mean when you say that names can be incremented.

Comment: That initializer is invalid for `names`. You must get a compiler error if you try it. But if you provided a valid initializer, `names` could be incremented.

Comment: To elaborate, `{ x, y }` can only be the initializer for an array with at least two elements. But you are trying to initialize a pointer.  It's not possible for the initializer to create an anonymous array and then the pointer points to the first element of that array. It is the same problem as this line has, `char const *c = { 'a', 'b', '\0' };`.